# Interceptor API : in a classic java project

Tags: java, ejb, interceptor

I want to add a listener on java method and I saw the annotation `@Interceptors` and `@AroundInvoke`.
I want to use it in a classic java project but all tutorials show me Java EE projects.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, those are managed by the Java EE container.
An easy way is to create a proxy/wrapper over all instances of your class.
Or use Spring AOP (but you will have to configure Spring) or AspectJ.
Check this out: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html

Answer (score 0):

Interceptor is a DI (Dependency injection) concept based on AOP (aspects oriented programming).

Since Java-ee 6 you have a lightweight DI container named CDI.
You can use CDI in a java-se context if you provide an implementation allowing a standalone deployment like jboss weld :

See [Is it possible to use javax.interceptor in a Java SE environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777865/is-it-possible-to-use-javax-interceptor-in-a-java-se-environment)

Otherwise, you can use spring, which also provides a lightweight DI container with the same kind of features and may be better suited for a java-se context usage.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the doc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html

> Interceptors are used in conjunction with Java EE managed classes to allow developers to invoke interceptor methods on an associated target class, in conjunction with method invocations or lifecycle events.

So I guess the answer to your question is no.