# Java CDI interceptor not working web application with WELD

Tags: java, tomcat, cdi, interceptor

I have created a web application which uses Weld-2.2.0 CDI implementation and runs on Tomcat-7. I have created an interceptor to log method calls. But when i run the application, it bypasses interceptor and calls method directly.

My interceptor constructs are as below:

Interceptor Binding:

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
public @interface LogMe{

}
```

Interceptor class:

```
@LogMe
@Interceptor
public class LogInterceptorImpl
{
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(LogInterceptorImpl.class);      

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception
    {
        log.debug("LogInterceptor::intercept");
        return ctx.proceed();
    }    
}
```

Interceptor Target:

```
@LogMe
public class DefaultAppController extends AbstractBaseController
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DefaultAppController()
    {

    }

    @Override @LogMe
    public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        resp.getWriter().write("Hello, Guest !");
    }

}
```

And finally i have created beans.xml file as below:

```
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
    <interceptors>
        <class>x.web.interceptors.LogInterceptorImpl</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

I have also created weld resource reference in context.xml file and web.xml file (as described by weld documentation.

```
<Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
```

And

```
<resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
```

I tried lots of optins including using weld-tomcat-support jar for integration but none of them seems to be working.

Can any one help me out here ?

Am i missing or doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Can you post the 'full' web.xml? (full being the XML header and all configuration but not stuff like your own listeners, servlets, etc.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think that interceptors are working outside a Java EE container. I guess standalone Weld can only do DI but not the other features. See also this post: [Is it possible to use javax.interceptor in a Java SE environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777865/is-it-possible-to-use-javax-interceptor-in-a-java-se-environment)

Comment: The question is probably if it works in a Servlet 3.0 environment or not - not specifically a JEE environment. It SHOULD work in Tomcat 7+, but you may need a properly up to date version. Tomcat 7.0.50+ most likely.

Comment: That's what I said. Tomcat runs in a Java SE environment and is no JEE container. So it is most likely that such features are not available in Tomcat. But if you say that Tomcat 7.0.50+ implements these features then it should work, yes.

Comment: Interceptors very much do work outside of EE containers.  Can you post the contents of your WEB-INF to see what JARs are getting put into your app?

Comment: Please also show where you inject your controller and call this method.

Comment: Thanks John for your valuable comment, may be i was missing one thing and that was injecting the class, but weld documentation says it injects into servlet by enabling a listener in to context.By the way WEB-INF listing is to long, not able to paste it here ! And how can i inject Servlet (DefaultAppController) ?